# Validation of incoming XML - should I use both a XSD file and in code validation

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

This is more a question rather than a technical problem asking for advice on the best way of validating XML.

I have a web service written in C#, that accepts incoming Xml requests.

Currently I am validating the incoming Xml against my XSD schema.  This works fine, I can capture any errors and respond with the appropriate message.

In addition, I have the following function which I can pass my object to, to validate all the properties;

```
    private List<ValidationResult> Validate(object oObject)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var context = new ValidationContext(oObject, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
        Validator.TryValidateObject(oObject, context, results, false);
        return results;
    }
```

And I validate the elements defined like;

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(175)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
```

The function returns a string list of any errors found.

Providing the XSD schema and class properties are in sync in terms of validation requirements, it would appear that my code would never return a list of results in the function

```
private List<ValidationResult> Validate(object oObject)
```

because the XSD schema prevents the code getting to that point.

Is this the normal way to perform XML validation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it is normal to perform both types of validation -- XSD and application-specific -- on a request.**

XSDs are a sharable (and executable) specification of the expectations of the request.  It's a win to be able to inform a client of request problems automatically in terms of the shared specification that an XSD is.

However, some checks cannot be expressed in an XSD (conveniently or at all).  For XSD 1.0, for example, see all of the motivational examples for XSD 1.1's `xs:assertion`.  Even for XSD 1.1, there will be cases where it may be necessary or preferable to implement checks on the request out-of-band wrt the XSD.  For example, an implementation-level check might be necessary while a service is implemented in a certain way, but the service interface needn't be permanently burdened with the check.  Or some complex, extant procedural code might be drawn upon to check some aspect of the request, and expressing than declaratively in the XSD might be impossible or unwieldy.

**Place as many validation constraints as possible in the XSD, but also retain checks that don't naturally fit there -- a second level of validation can be valuable and practical.**